# R Error in tapply arguments must have same length

Tags: list, r

Есть набор данных, имена некоторых колонок числа (года).
При попытке автоматизировать создание сводной таблицы получается ошибка.

```
df <- read.table(text = "value  class   2000    2001    2002
             123    class1  subclass1   subclass3   subclass1
             564    class1  subclass1   subclass3   subclass2
             564    class1  subclass1   subclass3   subclass3
             213    class2  subclass1   subclass4   subclass4
             856    class2  subclass1   subclass5   subclass4
             22 class3  subclass6   subclass6   subclass4
             5  class4  subclass1   subclass3   subclass4", header = TRUE)

names(df) <- c("value", "class", "2000", "2001", "2002")
```

Так работает без проблем:

```
data.frame(with(df, tapply(value, INDEX = list(class, `2000`), FUN = sum)))
data.frame(with(df, tapply(value, INDEX = list(class, `2001`), FUN = sum)))
data.frame(with(df, tapply(value, INDEX = list(class, `2002`), FUN = sum)))
```

Если попытаться сделать это циклом выдает ошибку.

```
years <- c("2000", "2001", "2002")
for (i in 1:3) {
  data.frame(with(df, tapply(value, INDEX = list(class, years[i]), FUN = sum)))
}

Error in tapply(value, INDEX = list(class, years[i]), FUN = sum) : 
  arguments must have same length
```

Может кто-то подсказать в чем моя ошибка и как её исправиль?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Причина ошибки в вашем коде в том, что вы передаёте строку, а нужно имя переменной (столбца). В вашем случае можно просто отказаться от конструкции `with`. Вот такая конструкция будет работать без ошибок:

```
tapply(df[["value"]], INDEX = list(df[["class"]], df[[years[1]]]), FUN = sum)
```

Функция `aggregate()` позволяет передать формулу в качестве аргумента. Саму формулу мы можем сформировать как текстовую строку.

```
f <- as.formula(sprintf("value ~ class + `%s`", years[1]))
aggregate(formula = f, data = df, FUN = sum)
```

Для агрегации более чем по одному индексу удобно использовать группировку данных, реализованную в пакете `dplyr`. Перед самой группировкой нужно преобразовать формат данных из широкого представления в длинный.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% gather(year, subclass, -value, -class) %>%
    group_by(class, subclass, year) %>% 
    summarise(sum = sum(value))
```

Результат:

```
Source: local data frame [15 x 4]
Groups: class, subclass [?]

class  subclass  year   sum
(fctr)     (chr) (chr) (int)
1  class1 subclass1  2000  1251
2  class1 subclass1  2002   123
3  class1 subclass2  2002   564
4  class1 subclass3  2001  1251
5  class1 subclass3  2002   564
6  class2 subclass1  2000  1069
7  class2 subclass4  2001   213
8  class2 subclass4  2002  1069
9  class2 subclass5  2001   856
10 class3 subclass4  2002    22
11 class3 subclass6  2000    22
12 class3 subclass6  2001    22
13 class4 subclass1  2000     5
14 class4 subclass3  2001     5
15 class4 subclass4  2002     5
```

Comment: Благодарю! То что нужно!